# How do I restore `git pull` functionality on Windows?

Tags: ssh, git, firewall

With no changes (to my knowledge) to my Windows 10 machine, I can no longer run `git pull` to pull changes to a repository. This is just a testing machine, I don't need to push changes, but I've been happily using `git pull`.

Last week I started seeing connection failure messages:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

After trying to give `git.exe` access through the firewall, I gave up, rebooted the
machine, and `git pull` started working again.

Today even reboots don't work.

I changed the `git remote` protocol to use `https` instead of `git` and I can `git pull`, but I'm curious about what's happened here.

Comment: Is Git working on your computer? Does it connect to other repositories? That error tells me that the connection is being refused at the target, not at your end. Have you checked the repository to make sure it's working OK?

Comment: Have you changed the certificates?
Is your system clock off-time? try `ssh -T git@github.com` from windows machine giving problems